# Delete more than 1000 records at a time from S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3

Need to delete more than 1000 records from s3 bucket , but its rejecting in promise and getting error as mentioned below

```
 async function removeS3Objects(audios) {
    //more than 1000 records are in audios
    audios = audios.map(item => {
      return {
        Key: item.Key
      };
    });
    let params = {
      Bucket: config.get("s3BucketName"),
      Delete: {
        Objects: audios,
        Quiet: false
      }
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      s3.deleteObjects(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

getting error while deleting

```
the xml you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot delete more than [1000 objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObjects.html) in one API call.

Straight from the docs

> The request contains a list of **up to 1000 keys** that you want to delete

If you want to delete more than 1000 keys you'll need to make multiple calls.